# SVG Manipulation or Vector graphics manipulation in Objective C

Tags: ios, mobile, svg

**Requirement**

In one of the projects I am working on I have following requirement:-

- A dynamic 2d object with different areas to be colored
- Support multiple angles

To make it more clear let's take an example where I will have a man's svg image wearing shorts and t-shirt. I want to color of shorts and t-shirt to be dynamic and also allow to switch between front and back pose.

**My Approach** 
I thought to use SVG graphic with two layers. First layer will represent front pose and second layer will represent reverse pose. I will show/hide layers based on which pose is to present. Both layers will have objects like shorts, t-shirt etc and their color will be dynamically handled.

**What I've explored** 
I did some research on https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit but not sure if it is good enough to support for what I need

Comment: I am looking for recommendations to do something like i mentioned.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok I will describe what I have done so far and update the question

Comment: I've written a library, SVGgh, available here: https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh There is a class in there called SVGRendererLayer which could be composed the way you describe. And it takes an SVGRenderer object which has a currentColor property, which could be used to change the colors of elements in the SVG that are marked to use currentColor as their fill property.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GlennHowes. I will spend some time on it and get back if any questions.